# Growing in the "Virtual bytes" performance counter

Tags: memory, windows-services, memory-leaks, performancecounter

I am suffering from an "Out of memory" exception in my Windows Service after running it for few hours under huge workload.
I used the following performance counters to detect memory leaks:

- ## bytes in all heap
- Private bytes
- Virtual bytes

The first 2 counters are going up and down regularly ... I cant see anything wrong in them.
but the 3rd one is growing very slowly by time, the counter is going up and down too but at the end it is increasing by time.
What does that mean?

My Win Service is .NET which is calling some functions from a C++ DLL and also using a 3rd party which have some unmanaged code in it.

Does this indicate a memory leak in the managed code / unmanaged code ? or simply this wont help?

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question. Are you allocating memory in your C# code? Can you post code?

Comment: The C++ DLLs are not my code, they are all third parties, I am allocating and releasing a lot of resources in my managed code, i cant post them all, they are too many, some of them are related to GDI+, ADO.NET and many other kinds of objects. I also believe that the unmanaged code is doing this frequently (due to its functionality)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [clr profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=86ce6052-d7f4-4aeb-9b7a-94635beebdda&displaylang=en) so you can monitor your usage.  If it only crashes under hudge load there may not be an error so much as a new design constraint to handle the load.

Comment: hmmm, I don't know why this profiler didn't like my Win Service, he is always showing a dialog box: "Waiting for service to start common language runtime", the profile is able to start the service but then he is showing that dialog box.